# Garbage in output and wrong strings printed

Tags: string, assembly, x86, nasm, dos

I'm using nasm , and I have to do this assembly program for class that is supposed to receive a password, compare with the one stored in `pass`, and write whatever the password is valid or not, however for some odd reason, when printing `cade` it yields garbage along with the string, and when to print the other two it prints `cade` instead along with `contr` and garbage, so I'm not really sure what's happening, and if someone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Here is the macro I use to print the string

```
%macro inout 2
mov ah,%2
mov dx,%1
int 21h
%endmacro
```

And here is the program

```
[bits 16]
%include "macros2.inc"

[segment .data]


cade: db 'Enter the password',0ah, 0dh,'$'
invalida: db 'wrong password',0ah, 0dh,'$'
valida: db 'valid password',0ah, 0dh,'$'
pass: db '12345$'
band: db 0
contr: resb 10

[segment .code]
..start
mov ax,data
mov dx,ax

inout cade,09h
mov bx,contr
mov ah,09h
mov dx,cade
int 21h
leer:
    mov ah,08h
    int 21h
    cmp al,0dh
    je checa
    mov [bx],al
    inc bx
    mov ah,02h
    mov dl, "*"
    int 21h
    jmp leer

checa:  
    lea di,[contr]
    lea si, [pass]
    dec si
revisa: 

    loadsb  
    inc di
    cmp [di],al
    jne error
    inc bx
    inc di
    cmp si,'$'
    jl revisa

mov ah,09h
mov dx,valida
int 21h
jmp fin

error:
mov ah,09h
mov dx,invalida
int 21h

fin:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h















[bits 16]
%include "macros2.inc"

[segment .data]


cade: db 'Introduzca la contrsena',0ah, 0dh,'$'
invalida: db 'Contraseña no Valida',0ah, 0dh,'$'
valida: db 'Contraseña valida',0ah, 0dh,'$'
pass: db '12345$'
band: db 0
contr: resb 10

[segment .code]
..start
mov ax,data
mov dx,ax

inout cade,09h
mov bx,contr
mov ah,09h
mov dx,cade
int 21h
leer:
    mov ah,08h
    int 21h
    cmp al,0dh
    je checa
    mov [bx],al
    inc bx
    mov ah,02h
    mov dl, "*"
    int 21h
    jmp leer

checa:  
    lea di,[contr]
    lea si, [pass]
    dec si
revisa: 

    loadsb  
    inc di
    cmp [di],al
    jne error
    inc bx
    inc di
    cmp si,'$'
    jl revisa

mov ah,09h
mov dx,valida
int 21h
jmp fin

error:
mov ah,09h
mov dx,invalida
int 21h

fin:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h}
```

Comment: What is `inout cade,09h` ?

Comment: Forgot about that, i a macro the recives the string label, and intrusciton to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't take long to find your first problem...

```
[segment .code]
..start
mov ax,data
mov dx,ax
```

I think you want that to be `ds`, not `dx`.

I see you reinvent `gets()`. How about checking that you don't overflow your buffer?

It isn't too clear what you're trying to do after that. How about some comments?